# Not able to connect Android Version 9 devices in Android Studio for debugging

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version

I am trying connect my Android device version 9 (Redmi Note 8 Pro) in Android Studio.

I am getting like below while trying to connect,

[image]

This versions included

- minSdkVersion 19
- targetSdkVersion 29

Enabled developer options in device and also enabled usb debugging.
Doesn't know how to debug version 9 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the USB preference as file transfer.try it